# Connection between partitions and equivalence classes

Tags: abstract-algebra

By a theorem, an equivalence class generates a partition, and the converse statement is also true. I know that the Bell numbers count the possible ways to generate such partitions, if I have $n$ elements in my set.

Now suppose I have a binary structure of two elements $(a,b)$. With them I can build $16$ multiplication tables. How many nonisomorphic binary structures are there? I feel I have to use the Bell numbers, but I don't have how to connect, say, a multiplication table with certain partition that I can generate.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Bell numbers.

Comment: There are only 16 of them, what's stopping you from simply listing them all and count?

Comment: There are $16$ of them, but the question is over the nonisomorphic multiplication tables. Besides, I was wondering if there is a general method to count all nonisomorphic structures with $n$ elements.